# Solve linear diophantine equation problem

Tags: diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

I am here again, but this time with a Diophantine equation problem.I (thought) know how to resolve a Diophantine equation, but can't get the equation of this problem

> Given a number of sweets we have that if we distribute the sweets to 3 chidren we still have 2 sweets and if we distribute the sweets to 11 children we still have 5 sweets. How many sweets will we have if we distribute the same amount of sweets within 33 children?

Many thanks for your help.

Edit: I need integer solution

Comment: Try with chinese reminder theorem

Comment: @Momo. Sorry, I forgot to mention that I need Integer solution, not a congruent number. Thanks

Comment: The question is poorly posed. You should write it so that it is clear that  each child receives an *equal* amount of sweets when they are "distributed".  Do you already know CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem or related results such as Bezout's gcd identity?

Comment: @Cako if you know the solution by congruence, then you know the solutions. Take a look [here](http://www.mathcelebrity.com/chinese.php?matrix1=x+%3D+2+mod+3%0D%0Ax+%3D+5+mod+11&pl=Solve+using+Chinese+Remainder+Theorem)

Comment: @Momo thanks for your link, but I need the solution expressed as a diophantine equation, I got the equation, the particular and general solution of it, but there are as far as I goes.

Comment: @BillDubuque I only knew of Bezout identity, Neither I  knew of the CRT before, nor appears on my teacher's notes. But thanks for mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

If $N$ is the number of sweets, then there must exists integers $a$ and $b$ such that
$$N = 3a + 2 \quad \text{and} \quad N = 11b + 5$$

So

$$11N = 33a + 22 \quad \text{and} \quad 3N = 33b + 15$$

Then

\begin{align}
   N &= 12N - 11N \\
   &= 4(3N) - 11N \\
   &= 4(33b + 15) - (33a + 22) \\
   &= 33(4b-a) + 38 \\
   &= 33(4b-a+1) + 5\\
   &= 33n + 5 \\
\end{align}

So the possible values of $N$ are $5, 38, 71, \dots , 33n+5, \dots$

Answer (score 0):

If each of the $3$ children gets $m$ sweets, and each of the 11 children gets $n$ sweets, then we must have $3m+2=11n+5$. Rearranging the terms shows that $3m-11n=3$, so we might have $m=1$ and $n=0$ for example. In this case the total number of sweets is $5$, so we would have $5$ sweets left if we distribute these $5$ sweets equally among $33$ children.

Are there other possible remainders?

Comment: The inference "so we would have 5 sweets left..." is a *big* leap if the OP does not already know the fundamentals.

Comment: @BillDubuque This is still in the context of the example values of $m$ and $n$; I edited to clarify this.